# Переменное число входных переменных в C#

Tags: c#

Сегодня ходил на собеседование, и одним из вопросов был:

> Как в метод передать переменное число переменных?

Первой мыслей было использование массива. Но, к сожалению, было уточнение, что использование массивов не предусмотрено.

Мне, к сожалению, кроме использования списка и массивов ничего в голову не пришло.
Интересно узнать возможные варианты.

Вопрос был в контексте С#.

P.S. Я написал: "реализовать перегрузку методов".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ключевое слово `params` -

```
void MyMethod(params object[] inputs)
{
}
```

Вызов

```
MyMethod(1, "dva", 3.0, false);
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

Comment: но это же все равно массив какого либо типа, разве нет?

Comment: @danilshik, да, но в вызывающем коде массивы не фигурируют в явном виде.

Comment: @mymedia интересно, всегда думал, что это просто ключевое слово, которое предназначен для удобства передачи совокупности параметров, которые заносятся в массив и только потом передаются в метод, поэтому я его и не указал

Comment: @danilshik: по сути Вы правы, так это и работает. Так что в какой-то мере Ваш вариант более правилен, нежели синтаксический сахар в лице params

Answer (score 13):

Грешно будет не упомянуть об `__arglist`!

Рассмотрим код:

```
public static decimal Sum(__arglist)
{
    ArgIterator i = new ArgIterator(__arglist);
    decimal result = 0;
    while (i.GetRemainingCount() > 0)
        result += (decimal)Convert.ChangeType(TypedReference.ToObject(i.GetNextArg()), typeof(decimal));
    return result;
}

...

Console.WriteLine(Sum(__arglist(-1, 12L, 4U, 0.25, 0.25m, 30UL))); // 45.5
```

Здесь используется *недокументированная* возможность C#

Дело в том, что `IL`, в который и компилируется наш С#, поддерживает `vararg`-конвенцию (то есть можно создавать функции с динамическим числом параметров, значения которых при вызове будут взяты с вершины стека. Это Вам не `params`, пакующий все переданное в массив)

Право пользоваться этим не советую: обычная упаковка в массив проходит в разы быстрее! Для чего же тогда данная возможность вообще была добавлена в `C#`? Дело в том, что благодаря этому Вы спокойно можете взаимодействовать с вариативными функциями из нативных библиотек:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl]
static extern int Foo(__arglist); // Нативная функция с переменным числом парметров
```

---

Давайте взглянем на `IL` следующего кода:

```
public static decimal SumParams(params object[] Objects) => 
    Objects.Aggregate(0m, (sum, i) => sum + (decimal)Convert.ChangeType(i, typeof(decimal)));

public static decimal SumVarargs(__arglist)
{
    ArgIterator i = new ArgIterator(__arglist);
    decimal result = 0;
    while (i.GetRemainingCount() > 0)
        result += (decimal)Convert.ChangeType(TypedReference.ToObject(i.GetNextArg()), typeof(decimal));
    return result;
}

...

SumParams(-1, 12L);
SumVarargs(__arglist(-1, 12L));
```

Сигнатура `SumParams`:

```
.method public hidebysig static valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal SumParams(object[]) cil managed // object[] -> decimal
```

Вызов `SumParams`:

```
ldc.i4.2
newarr [mscorlib]System.Object // new object[2] a

dup
ldc.i4.0
ldc.i4.m1
box [mscorlib]System.Int32
stelem.ref // a[0] = (object)(-1)

dup
ldc.i4.1
ldc.i4.s 12
conv.i8
box [mscorlib]System.Int64 
stelem.ref // a[1] = (object)((long)12)

call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::SumParams(object[]) // сам вызов
```

Теперь же сигнатура `SumVarargs`:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    vararg valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal SumVarargs() cil managed // () -> decimal
```

Как видите, параметров у метода не указано вовсе! Лишь ключевое слово `vararg` помогает нам понять, что это [вариативная функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Вызов `SumVarargs`:

```
ldc.i4.m1 // -1

ldc.i4.s 12
conv.i8 // (long)12

call vararg valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal Program::SumVarargs(..., int32, int64) // сам вызов
```

Легко заметить, что никакой упаковки в массив в данном коде нет. Объекты кладутся на стек, а метод вызывается так, будто бы его сигнатура выглядит как-то так: `(int, long) -> decimal`. Но на деле типы параметров указаны лишь для того, чтобы понимать что и в каком количестве забирать со стека)

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант, пусть уж все в одном месте будет.

Если необходимо переменное число параметров из фиксированного списка, можно обойтись без перегрузки, используя для параметров значения по-умолчанию и именованное обращение к ним при вызове.

Например:

```
void ExampleMethod(int a = 0, double b = 0.0, string c = ""){}
```

Обращение:

```
//без именования параметров порядок при обращении важен
//Так можно
ExampleMethod(10);
ExampleMethod(10, 3.3);
ExampleMethod(10, 3.3, "");
//Так нельзя
ExampleMethod(3.3, "");

//При именованном обращении порядок не важен
ExampleMethod(a:10, b:3.3, c:"");
ExampleMethod(b:3.3, a:10, c:"");
ExampleMethod(c:"", a:10);
ExampleMethod(b:3.3);
```

Comment: Ну, это, наверное, все же статическое количество параметров, а не переменное. Просто параметры с предопределенными значениями. Не думаю что на собеседованиях такой ответ примут за правильный. А если и примут, то с очень большой натяжкой.

Comment: @Andrew тут все зависит от формулировки вопроса. Для вызывающего кода число параметров вполне себе переменное, хоть и ограниченное, о чем я явно написал в самом начале. По мне без этого варианта, как и перегрузки, предложенной автором, в общем-то ответ будет не полным. Выбор зависит от решаемой задачи. Хотя конечно будет зависеть от уровня собеседования и собеседующего.

Comment: @Andrew: по сути единственный метод, который действительно создаёт функцию с переменным числом параметров, описан в моем ответе. Но я очень сомневаюсь, что где-то есть настолько «прошаренные» люди, способные задать сей вопрос с ожиданием именного такого ответа. А с точки зрения вызывающего кода и перегрузки, и `params`, и параметры по умолчанию вполне себе выглядят как методы с переменным числом параметров. А вот `__arglist`, кстати, визуально так не выглядит из-за обрамления параметров в `__arglist(...)`) Вот так забавно получается)